Russell's-Paradox. Why can't something be true and false at the same time?
Since the real world allows something that is false to be true at the same time, why doesn't math support this fact?
In Quantum mechanics a cat in Schrodinger's box is dead and alive at the same time.   You could also have the box constructed so that Russell's set of all sets that don't contain themselves would exist in a superposition.
You can put a barber (the barber who shaves those men who don't shave themselves and only shaves them) in a Schrodinger box with an electron emitter.  Tell the barber to shave himself if the electron is spin up and not shave himself if the electron is spin down.  Then close the box and inside you will have the barber who is in a superposition of having shaved himself and not shaved himself at the same time.

They can in a paraconsistent logic.

This is a valid question.  What is with the downvotes?

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/

In contrast to Zermelo’s, von Neumann’s and Quine’s strategies, which are in a sense purely set theoretic, there have also been attempts to avoid Russell’s paradox by altering the underlying logic.

Mathematics just wouldn't be very useful if it supported this supposed "fact" of yours.

I don't think that this is a bad question, not sure about the quantum mechanics, though.
First of all, there are people (philosophers mostly) who are not afraid to welcome some statements of the form $A\leftrightarrow \neg A$ or even $A \land \neg A$ in mathematics. One of their arguments is that inconsistency itself is not the problem, only triviality is. By inconsistency I mean that a contradiction is provable and by triviality I mean that every sentence is provable. These two properties of formal systems are connected in classical logic through so-called principle of explosion ($\bot\rightarrow p$) -- in other words, classical logic allows you to derive any proposition $p$ from a contradiction, so any classical inconsistent system is also trivial. Now, triviality is not welcomed even by philosophers (at least usually ;)) since we would really like for some mathematical statements, e.g. those that would interfere with our sensible counting of apples, that they are unprovable.
Then classical logic is not usable if we want to keep some contradictions, so we have to dive into non-classical logics like paraconsistent logics. Very natural requirement would also be to try to keep the axiom of unrestricted comprehension (wiki) that we got rid of in Zermelo-Fraenkel axiomatic theory because it was the source of contradictions (and thus of triviality). But it turns out that such logic, that prevents the triviality and preserves the unrestricted comprehension has to be very very weak, see Meyer et al. (1979): Curry's paradox (jstor).
One attempt to construct a non-trivial paraconsistent set theory is from Weber (2010): Transfinite numbers in paraconsistent set theory (cambridge). In the article, the author tries to reconstruct some basic facts of modern mathematics (e.g. about ordinal numbers) in paraconsistent naive set theory and for you most importantly, Russell's paradox and Burali-Forti paradox are just theorems in his system.

Sorry , I am not that familiar with the trivialities.  Every sentence is provable because in QM everything is possible.  The more absurd things just have a much much lower probability.   Russell's teapot could be out there in space but the probability is very low.   The barber shaving himself is 50/50.  Which slit the electron passes through is 50/50. If you run at a brick wall, and keep doing it , eventually you will tunnel through the wall and appear on the other side without a scratch.  The human body has a wavelength just like an electron.

I doubt your interpretation of quantum mechanics, @JeffGuarino.

Not my interpretation.I am quoting my third year quantum physics professor.He also told us that we humans are particles with a wavelength.  A very small wavelength.  If you run on the roof of a tall building to commit suicide there is a small probability that you will get reflected at the precipice and find yourself running in the opposite direction.You understand that these probabilities are almost zero but not zero. You won't see these things ever happen for googleplex years.  Electrons have very noticeable waves as in the tunnel diode and the larger the particle the smaller the wavelength.

They can in paraconsistent logics, which are precisely logics in which the principle of explosion doesn't hold.
The Principle of Explosion: A contradiction implies anything.
See, for instance, relevant logics.

Paraconsistent logics have applications in, for instance, law (when there are conflicting testimonials) and data corruption (when conflicting data needs to be contained, instead of there being an explosion of nonsense).

It should be noted though, that paraconsistency doesn't save Russell's paradox. We can very easily modify the paradox so that it implies every proposition, without using explosion.

In particular, fix a proposition $p$, and $R_p = {x : x \in x \to p}$. Then $R_p \in R_p$ iff $R_p \in R_p \to p$ by the same logic, so we can deduce $p$. This means the logic is still trivial, unless we further cut down on the rules of implication $\to$, or turn to substructural logic.

I'm aware of such modifications, @Trebor.  (Well, of the Liar Paradox at least.)  For example, "this sentence is either false, or neither true nor false" would be one, which would then be codified into the logic at hand if we suppose it has the truth value "neither true nor false". Is this what you mean or am I way off?

@Shaun I think he means, that if we are talking about allowing Russell's contr. to be provable in our system, then we are probably also talking about allowing unrestricted comprehension in our system. It turns out that such a system has to be very very weak -- one major problem being the so-called Curry's paradox (which Trebor pointed out explicitly). There is a short readable article about how weak we have to actually go: Meyer et al. (1979): Curry's paradox (link). In other words, it has to be weaker than most known paracon. and relevant logics.

I am afraid that a quantum superposition is a new animal.  You need to introduce quantum physics and leave Newtons classical world.  The 7 bridge problem in Königsberg is a good example.  If you shrink the map down to nano size then an electron can cross all 7 bridges once.  In fact it can cross all 7 at the same time. Nothing is ever 100% true or 100% false.  It is always fuzzy.  This introduces waves into math that no math allows. Humans have a wavelength also of about 10^-32 m.  So there is a non zero probability to cross all 7 bridges once.

You cannot solve Russel's paradox with quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanics says that a system can exist under multiple superposed states, but that as soon as you observe it, one single state can remain. That mean that as soon as the barber will get out of the box (what he will have to do to shave its clients), you will be able to ask him whether he shaves himself. And whatever his answer will be, it will lead to the contradiction.

When you have a superposition ,  you simply never observe it and the state never collapses.   You leave the barber in the box.   Also while in the box the superposition exist and is a solution.   If you open the box after 1000 years and the wave collapses does not obviate what the state was for the 1000 years.  It existed.  Also if you have a problem with Schrodinger's cat in the box then you can substitute a nano sized equivalent system and just change the actors.

Since the whole universe is QM , even Russell's paradox is part of the unitary wavefunction.  Logic is also and you can't escape it.   So at some level you will find the solution in QM.  Newton's classical world does not exist. It is an approximation of QM.

In the double slit exp, if you try to figure which slit the electron passes through, you destroy the superposition. When you don't "look" then the superposition is not collapsed at the slits but at the screen.   The information determining the location of the electron is not a valid question.   So when you put the barber in the superposition you make the original question moot. The question "who shaves the barber" is something you can't ask.
